# Freeing unused allocated nodes on a SLURM cluster

Tags: gnu-parallel, slurm

I'm running some batches of serial programs on a (very) inhomogeneous SLURM cluster (version 2.6.6-2), using [GNU 'parallel'](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) to do the distribution. The problem that I'm having is that some of the nodes finish their tasks a lot faster than the others, and I end up with situations like, for example, a job that's allocating 4 nodes but is only using 1 during half of the simulation.

Is there any way, without administrator privileges, to free one of these unused nodes? I can mitigate the problem by running 4 jobs on individual nodes, or with files containing lists of homogeneous nodes, but it's still far from ideal.

For reference, here are the script files that I'm using (adapted from [here](http://docs.rcc.uchicago.edu/software/scheduler/parallel/README.html))

**job.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

#SBATCH --job-name=test
#SBATCH --time=96:00:00
#SBATCH --ntasks=16
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=1024
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=4
#SBATCH --partition=normal

# --delay .2 prevents overloading the controlling node
# -j is the number of tasks parallel runs so we set it to $SLURM_NTASKS
# --joblog makes parallel create a log of tasks that it has already run
# --resume makes parallel use the joblog to resume from where it has left off
# the combination of --joblog and --resume allow jobs to be resubmitted if
# necessary and continue from where they left off
parallel="parallel --delay .2 -j $SLURM_NTASKS"
$parallel < command_list.sh
```

**command_list.sh**

```
srun --exclusive -N1 -n1 nice -19 ./a.out config0.dat
srun --exclusive -N1 -n1 nice -19 ./a.out config1.dat
srun --exclusive -N1 -n1 nice -19 ./a.out config2.dat

...

srun --exclusive -N1 -n1 nice -19 ./a.out config31.dat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `scontrol` command to downsize your job:

```
scontrol update JobId=# NumNodes=#
```

I am not sure however how Slurm chooses the nodes to dismiss. You might need to choose them by hand and write

```
scontrol update JobId=# NodeList=<names>
```

See Question 24 in the [Slurm FAQ](http://slurm.schedmd.com/faq.html).